# Diplay item with name contained in an array

Tags: powershell

Ok, I'm kinda new to PowerShell and I want to do what it seems to be a simple task but I don't know how to do it...

So, I have a folder with 3 documents in it : **blueberry.txt** ; **savage.txt** ; **yellowstone.txt**

I also have a list of words :

**yellow ; red ; blue**

I want to only get the documents with names matching with at least one of the word contained into my array.

I wrote this :

```
$List = @("yellow","red","blue")

Get-ChildItem C:\TestFolder | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $List}
```

This returns nothing and I think I know why. I think each object are compared to all the words in my array and the condition can be true only if the name of my item match with all of the words in my array.

I can get what I want if I do :

```
Get-ChildItem C:\TestFolder | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $List.GetValue(0) -or $_.Name -match $List.GetValue(1) -or $_.Name -match $List.GetValue(2)}
```

But it's quite messy. Also, imagine if my array contained much more words... lol

I don't know if I'm making myself clear, I'm not that good with english.

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Comment: a simpler solution is to convert your `$List` into a regex OR pattern & then use `$Collection.Where({$_.Name -match $RegexList})`.

Comment: `dir | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $($List -join '|')}` should do the trick…

Comment: Thanks both of you for your comments but I think a foreach statement is better.
Also, nice trick @JosefZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading myself I solve this stupid question LMAO.

```
foreach($word in $List) {
Get-ChildItem C:\TestFolder | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $word}
}
```

I'm such an idiot.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven Thanks for the kind words :)